# Issue "Found cycle for field" while using mongodb with spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using mongodb with spring

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

All things worked fine until the moment when it print the following warnings

> 2019-08-28 07:10:01.672  INFO 9558 --- [  restartedMain]
>   m.c.i.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver : Found cycle for field
>   'endpoints' in type 'SocketBase' for path 'monitorSocket ->
>   monitorSocket'
>
> 2019-08-28 07:10:01.672  INFO 9558 --- [
>   restartedMain] m.c.i.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver : Found cycle
>   for field 'waitStatus' in type 'Node' for path 'prev -> prev'
>
> 2019-08-28 07:10:01.672  INFO 9558 --- [  restartedMain]
>   m.c.i.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver : Found cycle for field
>   'waitStatus' in type 'Node' for path 'prev -> next -> prev'

It still working but it take so much time to launch the application although after disabling the logs

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index=OFF
```

below preview of some models used

```
 @Document(collection="Nodes")
 public class Node {
    @Id 
    private String idNode;
    private String name;                
    private List<Microservice> microServices;
   }


   @Document(collection="Applications")
   public class Application {

    @Id                    
    private String name;             
    private List<Node> nodes;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private List<NodeComponent> nodeComponents = new ArrayList();
    ..
    }
```

Any suggestion

Comment: can you add documents structure, with only `@embedded`, `@referrence` entity

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that in your Entities you have coherent types, in my case it was the 
**ZeroMQ Zcontext** which posed the problem.
However you can you use the **@Transient** annotation to ignore the attribute by Mongo

```
@Transient
ZContext context;
```

Best regards ;)